# HTML to PDF with python and wkhtmltopdf

Tags: python, django, wkhtmltopdf, python-bindings

I have just found [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), amazing html converter using webkit. I have tried it on my dev machine and its simple and works well.

*How can this best be integrated with a django based site?*

I found the [python bindings](https://github.com/mreiferson/py-wkhtmltox), but they presume a certain level of understanding of how to install things I just don't have. e.g.

```
you need libwkhtmltox.* somewhere in your LD path (/usr/local/lib)
you need the directory src/include/wkhtmltox from wkhtmltopdf
    somewhere on your include path (/usr/local/include)
```

- After installing those python bindings, how do I use them? What calls can I do?
- Does the resulting pdf have to be saved to the hd or can I stream it out of a view with something?

For example:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+letter_name
response['Content-Type'] = 'Content-type: application/octet-stream'
response['Content-Length'] = bytes
return response
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend [django-wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf) for this purpose. Their [usage documentation](https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/docs/usage.rst) gives a few examples on how to integrate:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateView


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
    url(r'^pdf/$', PDFTemplateView.as_view(template_name='my_template.html',
                                           filename='my_pdf.pdf'), name='pdf'),
    # ...
)
```